# Significato di "monatto" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning

In questa [notizia di Euronews](https://it.euronews.com/2020/04/20/spagna-minacce-contro-medici-e-infermieri) ho letto questo testo che ha attirato la mia attenzione perché c'era una parola che non conoscevo, "monatto" (grassetto mio):

> Esiste però l'altra faccia della medaglia. Il personale medico è spesso offeso, quando non minacciato. Medici e infermieri sono considerati **monatti** o untori e le reti sociali non fanno che amplificare quest'odio verso persone che, è bene ricordarlo, rischiano letteralmente la vita quotidianamente.

La mia domanda è sul suo significato in questo brano. Sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/monatto) ho trovato che questa definizione per questo termine:

> Nome, reso famoso dal Manzoni nella descrizione della peste del 1630, con cui erano indicati a Milano i «serventi pubblici ... addetti ai servizî più penosi e pericolosi della pestilenza: levar dalle case, dalle strade, dal lazzeretto, i cadaveri; condurli sui carri alle fosse, e sotterrarli; portare o guidare al lazzeretto gl'infermi, e governarli; bruciare, purgare la roba infetta e sospetta» (*Promessi Sposi*, cap. XXXII).

E anche sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI10/00000776.jpg) si legge:

> **Monatto**, sm. Inserviente  pubblico  che,  du­rante  le  epidemie  (in  partic.  di  peste),  era  ad­detto  al  trasferimento dei malati al lazza­retto, al servizio di infermeria, al trasporto e alla  sepoltura  dei  cadaveri  e  alla  distruzione degli  oggetti  contagiosi;  portava,  come  di­stintivo,  un  campanello  legato  a  un  piede,  che serviva per avvisare della sua presenza.

Si capisce bene. Tuttavia, il contesto del brano che ha generato la mia domanda non è un'epidemia di peste avvenuta in passato, ma l'attuale pandemia di COVID-19. Ricercando "monatto" e "coronavirus" su Google se ne trovano altre occorrenze in questo stesso contesto. Ecco alcuni esempi ([1](http://www.stadiotardini.it/2020/04/infermieri-sul-fronte-del-covid-19-la-testimonianza-arianna-pinetti-le-poesie-alessandra-marinelli-video-dellomaggio-delle-forze-dellordine.html), [2](https://www.peopleforplanet.it/covid-19-diario-di-24-ore-al-pronto-soccorso-del-policlinico-di-milano/), [3](http://nuovabrianza.it/coronavirus-monza-tra-follia-e-praticita/)):

> Sei stanco di sentirti più un "monatto" che un infermiere.

> Io ho fatto il tampone: sono io il monatto che li infetterà.

> Se poi contiamo i monatti del terzo millennio che sfidano i tempi e chiari di luna ostentando sicurezza e competenza da premio Nobel sul come fare l'amuchina in casa, siamo quasi al completo.

Capisco che se ne fa un uso figurato. Comunque, non riesco a capire del tutto bene perché si utilizza questo vocabolo. Perciò, vi chiedo: come dovrei interpretare il senso di "monatto" in questo contesto?

Comment: I monatti non avevano una buona fama: “All’impiego di monatti e d’apparitori non s’adattavano generalmente che uomini sui quali l’attrattiva delle rapine e della licenza potesse più che il terror del contagio, che ogni naturale ribrezzo. ... si fecero, i monatti principalmente, arbitri d’ogni cosa. Entravano da padroni, da nemici nelle case, e, senza parlar de’ rubamenti, e come trattavano gl’infelici ridotti dalla peste a passar per tali mani, le mettevano, quelle mani infette e scellerate... [segue]”

Comment: ”...quelle mani infette e scellerate, sui sani, figliuoli, parenti, mogli, mariti, minacciando di strascinarli al lazzeretto, se non si riscattavano, o non venivano riscattati con danari. Altre volte, mettevano a prezzo i loro servizi, ricusando di portar via i cadaveri già putrefatti, a meno di tanti scudi. Si disse ... che monatti e apparitori lasciassero cadere apposta dai carri robe infette, per propagare e mantenere la pestilenza, divenuta per essi un’entrata, un regno, una festa” (_Promessi sposi_, cap. XXXII).

Comment: Prima che me lo dica qualcuno: ok, scrivo una risposta.

Comment: (Charo, hai letto i Promessi sposi? È un romanzo molto migliore di quanto sembri ai ragazzini italiani obbligati a leggerlo o a chi ha brutti ricordi scolastici.)

Comment: @DaG: Mi hanno raccontato molte cose dei *Promessi sposi*, ma non l'ho letto (e si vede, no?). Me n'ha parlato persino qualche italiano che considerava che, da ragazzo, non l'aveva capito. Ma poi l'aveva riletto da adulto e era stato un'altra cosa...

Comment: @Charo Lo lessi, come si usava, in seconda superiore e lo trovai ovviamente pesante perché si dovevano fare riassunti e parafrasi. Lo ripresi durante le vacanze di Natale quando facevo la quinta e lo lessi in tre giorni, tanto mi appassionò. Lo rileggo di tanto in tanto; ho anche comprato la “ventisettana”, cioè la seconda versione (la prima era “Fermo e Lucia”) per fare il paragone con l'edizione definitiva dopo il risciacquo dei panni in Arno.

Comment: @egreg: Adesso sono impegnata in altre letture, ma si tratta sicuramente di un romanzo da mettere nella lista di libri da leggere. Eh, sì, questo dei riassunti da fare a scuola era a volte un po' come una tortura. Quando ero piccola dovetti persino fare dei riassunti di una serie televisiva di cartoni animati basati sul Chisciotte, ed era anche una tortura il dover essere legati alla TV ogni fine settimana per poter fare i compiti.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'uso che si fa di “monatto” in quell'articolo è chiaramente negativo (oltre che figurato), il che non si spiegherebbe se i monatti fossero stati soltanto dipendenti pubblici addetti all'assistenza ai malati, al trasporto dei cadaveri e alle pulizie.

In realtà i monatti non avevano una buona fama. Come racconta Manzoni nel cap. XXXII dei *Promessi sposi*, non molto dopo il passo citato nel Treccani:

> All’impiego di monatti e d’apparitori non s’adattavano generalmente che uomini sui quali l’attrattiva delle rapine e della licenza potesse più che il terror del contagio, che ogni naturale ribrezzo. ... si fecero, i monatti principalmente, arbitri d’ogni cosa. Entravano da padroni, da nemici nelle case, e, senza parlar de’ rubamenti, e come trattavano gl’infelici ridotti dalla peste a passar per tali mani, le mettevano, quelle mani infette e scellerate, sui sani, figliuoli, parenti, mogli, mariti, minacciando di strascinarli al lazzeretto, se non si riscattavano, o non venivano riscattati con danari. Altre volte, mettevano a prezzo i loro servizi, ricusando di portar via i cadaveri già putrefatti, a meno di tanti scudi. Si disse ... che monatti e apparitori lasciassero cadere apposta dai carri robe infette, per propagare e mantenere la pestilenza, divenuta per essi un’entrata, un regno, una festa.

Quindi, più che persone al servizio del pubblico, erano degli sciacalli, dei profittatori, nonché perpetuavano l'epidemia stessa; a quel che dice quell'articolo, a quanto pare ci sarebbe chi ha un'opinione simile del personale medico odierno.

Comment: Quindi, erano anche sospetti di essere untori? (perlomeno ho letto il romanzo di Bufalino un paio di volte...)

Comment: @Charo: È solo una _diceria_... ;)

Comment: Come racconta il Manzoni, i monatti venivano reclutati tra i peggiori individui della società (delinquenti, gente che non aveva niente da perdere); da qui l'accezione negativa del termine.

Comment: @Charo se gl'infermieri di oggi vengono tacciati di "monattismo" (solo da pochi per fortuna), figuriamoci a quei tempi, per maggiore ignoranza e per il tipo di persone che erano i monatti!